Copying generated files relative to another target's executable
Is it possible with CMake to copy files generated from add_custom_command relative to $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${Target}>?
My use case specificly is compiled script files which must be in a specific folder Resources/Script in order for the application to function.
So I have
add_custom_command( OUTPUT ${CompiledFile} COMMAND ${ScriptCompiler} DEPENDS ${ScriptFile} )

add_library( CompiledScripts ${CompiledFile} )

add_executable( Main main.cpp ) 

Now I have tried various tools to get ${CompiledFile} into $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${Target}>/Resources/Script, the most common suggestion I found where:

add_custom_target, which has two issues TARGET_FILE_DIR adds a dependency, meaning the executable cannot depend on the custom target meaning a change to the scripts won't trigger the copy of the compiled files, meaning the copy is a manual operation. and secondly a custom target is always considered out of date, making it difficult to avoid unneeded copies.
add_custom_command( TARGET POST_BUILD ) which has similar issues where it is unaware of any changes made the the scripts and will make unneeded copies


"TARGET_FILE_DIR adds a dependency" - It is no longer true for CMake 3.19 or above: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/policy/CMP0112.html.

The solution I landed on is as follows:
Define your CompiledScripts target as usual, defining custom commands and listing their output as sources.
Use add_custom_command( TARGET CompiledScripts POSTBUILD COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/modified.cpp ) to modify a .cpp file each time CompiledScripts is build.
Create a library with modified.cpp as a source and give it an add_custom_command( TARGET POST_BUILD ) to copy the files where you need them. This creates an implicit/hidden dependency between CompiledScripts and this copy target, causing the POST_BUILD to run whenever CompiledScripts is rebuild. I have not found better solution, unfortunatly.
You can then use add_dependency to create the following chain CompiledScript => CopyTarget => Main. ( A=>B, B depends on A )
This has the benefit that the copying is only done if the files are actually modified, additionally you can modify modified.cpp from other targets to force the files to be recopied.
As noted by @Tsyvarev, using TARGET_FILE_DIR as the destination requires CMAKE 3.19 or the use of CMP0112.
